# How to add body in the request and get in second rest service in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I am trying to use `POST` to send data from one rest service to another rest service.

first.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");

var router = express.Router();

var options = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3000",
  path: "/second",
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ foo: "foo" })
};

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  http.request(options);
});

module.exports = router;
```

second.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("Hello");
});

module.exports = router;
```

It returns empty object {}. Does anyone know how to send JSON body from one service to another service.

app.js

```
app.use("/first", first);
app.use("/second", second);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely not **sending** the request body, but **reading** it.

In order to process the body, you need to use a middleware. Generally you'll use `bodyParser.json` ([Docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), check bottom for examples)

```
// In second.js, in addition to your other stuff
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This will allow it to parse the JSON.

The other step is on the sending side (`first.js`). You'll need to add the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Those two things will allow `second.js` to properly read the body and make it available.

Comment: what is app in second.js here `app.use(bodyParser.json());` ? I already have this in app.js `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` or do we need to add this in second.js too ?

Comment: It depends exactly how things are setup, so the answer is maybe. You definitely need the header `Content-Type: application/json` bit, so try that first. If it still doesn't work, try adding it in `second.js` as well.